# How to change button's caption (kartik FileInput widget)

Tags: php, yii2, widget

I have a problem. I use FileInput for uploading files. I don't use its default assets, so thats why I can't change browseLabel, it just doesn't work  for me.

```
//$this->registerAssets()
```

Can you help me how to change the caption. Now I have "Select" but I want "Please attach files"

Answer (score 0):

U can set the plugin option browseLabel and change it https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#browseLabel